# jquery dataTable reorder plugin drag is working but drop is not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js plugins to reorder my data Drag is working but drop is not working, it goes to the same position on mouse leave over. Below are the code.

```
   <table class="table-bordered table dataTable" id="hotbuystable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Brand Name</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <?php $count=0; foreach($getHotBuys as $keys => $item) {
                $count=$count+1;
                $cid = $item['phone_id'];
                echo "<tr data-position='$count' id='$cid'>";
                echo "<td><img src='" . $item['image'] . "' width='50px' height='50px'></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['brand_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['product_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['score'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td id='$cid'><a href='#' class='rowtag' id='$cid'><i class=\"fa fa-times fa-1x\"></i></a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.min.new.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery-select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery-datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"></script>

jQuery(function ($) {

    'use strict';

     $('#hotbuystable').dataTable({
         "bPaginate": false,
         "bFilter": false,
         "bInfo": false,
         "bSort": false
     }).rowReordering();
});
```

Can you please notice what is the error.

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle demo with the final HTML rendering (instead of php codes)?

Answer (score 1):

`rowReorder` requires that you have an index column and give all the `<tr>`'s an unique `id`. You already have `id` on the rows, so  :

```
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Image</th>
  <th>Brand Name</th>
  <th>Product Name</th>
  <th>Priority</th>
  <th>Remove</th>
</tr>
```

...

```
<?php $count=0; foreach($getHotBuys as $keys => $item) {
  $count=$count+1;
  $cid = $item['phone_id'];
  echo "<tr data-position='$count' id='$cid'>";
  echo "<td>" . $count . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td><img src='" . $item['image'] . "' width='50px' height='50px'></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $item['brand_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $item['product_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $item['score'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id='$cid'><a href='#' class='rowtag' id='$cid'><i class=\"fa fa-times fa-1x\"></i></a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

The index column does not have to be visible, you can hide it like this :

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
  rowReorder: true,
  columnDefs : [ { targets : [0], visible: false } ]
});
```

---

When you have a table based on HTML markup (not a datasource) then you can create the index column programmatically before initializing the dataTable  :

```
$('<th>').text('#').prependTo($('#example thead tr'))
$("#example tbody tr").each(function(i, tr) {
  $(tr).attr('id', 'id'+i)
  $('<td>').text(i).prependTo(tr)
})
```

The above populates the table with a `#` index column and gives each `<tr>` an unique `id`.